# How to preserve the state of toggle button in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, state, togglebutton

i have listview with toggle button.i face a problem when i scroll down the toggle button the state of toggle button changed,and also when i click on first toggleButton the fourth toggle button also checked. i also want to save the all toggle button states and the text on that particular row in arraylist. I also want to preserve toggle button state when app is closed .

i tries to use holder but its not work.

the below is my code

```
    public class CustomUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
        public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
            super(context, 0, users);
        }

   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
    //Get an instance of our cell holder                                                                         
        final Holder holder;

        holder = new Holder();

      // Get the data item for this position
      User user = getItem(position);    
         // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    holder.tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
    //final ToggleButton tgbtn = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    holder.tvName.setText(user.name);
    holder.tvHome.setText(user.hometown);
  //  holder.tgbtn.setTag(position);
    /** The clicked Item in the ListView */
   RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;

    /** Getting the toggle button corresponding to the clicked item */
 holder.tgbtn = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(2);


  holder.tgbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (holder.tgbtn.isChecked()) {
                 holder.tgbtn.setChecked(true);
                 String homet=holder.tvHome.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),homet+"Blocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    holder.tgbtn.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Unblocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
        });


     // Return the completed view to render on screen
      return convertView;
        }


   private class Holder{

   TextView tvName;
   TextView tvHome;

   ToggleButton tgbtn,tg1;

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i scroll down the toggle button the state of toggle button
>   changed

Because currently `getView` method not implemented using `ViewHolder` Pattern in right way.

See following tutorial to implement `getView` method using `ViewHolder` :

[Performance Tips for Android’s ListView](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

> when i click on first toggleButton the fourth toggle button also
>   checked

Because `holder.tgbtn` object of `ToggleButton` is used for check state of ToggeleButton on `onClick`. `holder.tgbtn` hold reference which is assigned during last call of `getView` method.

Use `v`  for getting text from TextView according to `ToggelButton`:

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
   TextView tvName = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
   //   Use  tvName to get TextView text 
  }
```